# appinsights java custom metric not working

Tags: java, azure, web, sdk, azure-application-insights

In a sample Java web application I tried to insert custom [metric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics)  but not seeing in the AppInsights metric explorer nor Customevents table. I see the following error in the console window.

Configuration file has been successfully found in: 'C:\Users...\WebAppCopy\WEB-INF\lib\ApplicationInsights.xml'
AI: ERROR 08-01-2017 18:14, 14: Failed to create empty class name
AI: ERROR 08-01-2017 18:14, 14: Failed to create DeadLockDetector, exception: null
AI: ERROR 08-01-2017 18:14, 14: Failed to create JvmHeapMemoryUsedPerformanceCounter, exception: null
Jan 08, 2017 6:14:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start

Comment: are the app insights jars/etc properly getting deployed to where the rest of your things are? it looks like the startup is failing to find things?

Comment: @JohnGardner My project includes [appinsights java sdk](https://aijavasdk.blob.core.windows.net/sdk/sdk.html) in its build path. Do I need to refer anything else? I don't see the namespaces of missing classes. Otherwise, I would have verified using a decompiler.

Comment: @Praveen Could you post the content of your `ApplicationInsights.xml` to improve your description for helping analysis the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the log traces in spite of the API error. It takes lot of time to reflect in AppInsight store - we can use developer mode setting for better consistency (not suggested in PROD).

Answer (score 0):

The printings are not the problem, it is an internal bug which will be fixed in the upcoming new version.

You can enable the internal logger  and check for possible errors.

You Can also send the me the ApplicationInsights.xml to gupele@microsoft.com

Comment: @PeterPan  I used the ApplicationInsight.xml file mentioned in the [appinsight article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-java-get-started) except for replacing the instrumentation key. Is this internal logger different from console logs I posted?